# Ubuntu 13.04 Black screen with nomodeset/xforcevesa/acpi=off

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, live-usb

When trying to boot and install Ubuntu 13.04 32 Bit Desktop edition, I am presented with a black screen. I have verified my ISOs md5sum, and have tried multiple flash drives. No combination of xforcevesa, acpi=off, and nomodeset have made any determinable difference.

The target, is slightly unique. The Kontron COMe-mSP1 is a low-power small form factor x86 PC, with an expansion board with USB, Gigabit ethernet, and a MicroSD card slot.

System:
http://us.kontron.com/nano

Processor:
http://ark.intel.com/products/35463

System Controller: 
http://ark.intel.com/products/35444/Intel-SCH-US15W

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately the support for this hardware is extremely limited on
>   Linux. There are several drivers, but all lack certain basic features,
>   such as future and current maintenance or support for suspend and
>   hardware acceleration.
>
> Currently, the best supported driver for Ubuntu is gma500_gfx.

Also:

> Ubuntu 12.10 +
>
> No workarounds should be required, however, upgrading from 12.04 is
>   not recommended because of general UI sluggishness.

From: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo which your unit has according to: http://us.kontron.com/nano

Maybe it's just generally slow and you don't see the difference because it takes too long to get an image, or drawing times out?